# Сравнение нескольких элементов (x == a) or (x == b) vs x in ( a, b)

Tags: python, python-3.x, if

Как правильнее сравнивать элементы в условии:

```
if (x == a) or (x == b):
```

или

```
if x in (a, b):
```

Во втором примере читаемость будет лучше при большом количестве элементов, но в первом интуитивно понятнее

Comment: любой ответ будет субъективен - и то, и то верно и дают одинаковый результат. дело вкуса

Answer (score 0, accepted):

читабельность и первого способа будет нормальной, если от лишних скобок избавиться:

```
if x == a or x == b
```

когда очень очень много переменных, то да, через кортеж удобнее немного

Comment: Как по мне, эти скобки как раз и предают читабельности, не надо знать порядок операций. Да и с кортежем короче и понятней, там только in, а в первом там и == и or и порядок их применения и символов больше